# How to work with push notification module in drupal7? and how to store device token?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am using push notifications module. One of my friend did an app for iphone. He gave me apns-development.pem file and i stored it in my drupal/pushnotification/certificates folder. now i have to give him the url or web service so that , using the web-service he can give device_token as parameter and that devicetoken should be stored in my database for sending push message for that particular device. Pls help me

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm the author of the Push Notifications module for Drupal. I wrote a brief tutorial about registering a device token using services here: http://www.danielhanold.com/story/drupal-7-push-notifications-how-to-register-a-device-token-using-services.

Comment: the link is offline and i´d like check it to use your module :)

Comment: @Tommy: I switched servers yesterday, the link from above should be online again. Please try again.

Comment: @haagendazs link is working now, thx. Could you have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21932833/push-notifications-drupal-module-remove-device) that i´ve posted last week, it´s about push_notifications module, any help would be appreciate. Thx

Comment: Hi @haagendazs - Is there a way to send push notifications to all registered devices when a new node of a particular content type is created? - Thank you for a wonderful module though, with these extensions I think the module would be more lovely.

Comment: @RaJ: I've integrated the module with the Rules module (https://drupal.org/project/rules). If you download the current dev version here https://drupal.org/project/push_notifications, you might be able to set this up with Rules.

Comment: @haagendazs I have followed the steps but got no success. Service enabled and configured. Posting token and type params as json but nothings happening.

Comment: @Devrim Have you tried turning on debug mode for Services? This might help you narrow down the issue. Here's a thread that discusses debug mode: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/70536/what-does-the-debug-mode-on-services-actually-do. I'd recommend to clear your log messages (unless you need them for anything else), attempt to post a token and then look at the new watchdog entries generated by the Services module.

Comment: @haagendazs Thanks for the reply! I've sorted it all out :)