# Push notifications Drupal module - Remove device (Web services)

Tags: php, web-services, drupal, drupal-7, push-notification

I´ve started to work with this module and i´ve managed to register devices (following the instructions of his author posted [here](http://www.danielhanold.com/story/drupal-7-push-notifications-how-to-register-a-device-token-using-services)).

Now i'm trying to unregister devices but when i send the http delete request (sending the token parameter with the value stored in DB) the message that i obtain is "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" and i have no idea what´s happening here.

I´ve been surfing the net but i didn´t find anything related to this...

If you need any additional info let me know.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

I´m using a java rest client ([RESTClient 3.2.1](https://code.google.com/p/rest-client/downloads/list)), which worked for register devices, to test these web services. 
To remove the device I´m setting a DELETE request pointing to this URL

http://www.myweb.com/ws-apps/push_notifications/**1234**

Where "1234" is the ID of a test device that I´ve saved before.

I´m still getting the error mentioned...

Comment: Can you confirm the endpoints? Are you using correct endpoints when you send a request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i´ve been able to discover where i was failing.

I was using this url

http://www.myweb.com/ws-apps/push_notifications/1234

But i forgot to specify the language too in the URL... Calling the following URL I was able to get this working.

http://www.myweb.com/en/ws-apps/push_notifications/1234

I hope this could be useful for someone else in future.